# Issue Weekly pattern RFC 5545 rrule

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, outlook, exchange-server

I trying to send ical recurrence using weekly pattern.

> DTEND:20150722T122500Z DTSTAMP:20150722T064401Z 
>     DTSTART:20150722T070000 LOCATION: ORGANIZER:MAILTO:Parthiban.qss@gmail.com
>     RRULE:FREQ=WEEKLY;UNTIL=20150805T151545Z;WKST=SU;BYDAY=MO,WE SEQUENCE:1 
>     SUMMARY:Test_1 UID:35791 END:VEVENT END:VCALENDAR

but the ical displayed only monday in exchange calendar, remaining Wednesday is not displayed.

Another one same problem in Daily.

How can i send weekdays only.

> RRULE:FREQ=DAILY;UNTIL=20150805T151545Z;BYDAY=MO,TU,WE,TH,FR  ?

If it is above one, it's not working. Please help me.

Thanks.

Comment: atleast format your code properly

Comment: Have you tried to save an appointment with the same recurrence pattern in Outlook as an ICS file and open it in Notepad?

Comment: this is my format, BEGIN:VCALENDAR VERSION:2.0 METHOD:REQUEST PRODID:-//DDay.iCal//NONSGML ddaysoftware.com//EN BEGIN:VEVENT ATTENDEE:MAILTO:parthirockfort@gmail.com CREATED:20170302T061559Z DTEND:20170302T171000Z DTSTAMP:20170302T061559Z DTSTART:20170302T104500 LOCATION: ORGANIZER:MAILTO:Parthiban.qss@gmail.com RRULE:FREQ=DAILY;UNTIL=20170315T190045Z;BYDAY=MO,TU,WE,TH,FR SEQUENCE:1 SUMMARY:Test daily UID:35806 END:VEVENT END:VCALENDAR